# How to obtain token when using app based OIDC in in-app browser

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, mobile-application

I have a question about best practices when it comes to OIDC in an app based context.

Most guides I have found explains such a setup in the context of the app being the client that will perform the token exchange directly with the IDP using the authorization code flow. This makes sense in many scenarios and there are several ready-to-use libraries out there, that can support this setup.
However, in my case, this is not an option since I need the backend to be client and the tokens (id, access and refresh) from the IDP to be kept secret i.e. stay within the backend.
When the tokens are obtained, certain actions are carried out and eventually a session is created. A session identifier (external token) will then have to be "handed over" to the app which will use it as authorization mechanism on subsequent requests. Simplified, it looks somthing like this:

`App => Session Manager => IDP`

The session manager acts as the client towards the IDP and provides a `/login` endpoint which the app will invoke through an in-app browser. `/login` will redirect to the `/authorize` endpoint of the IDP and the authorization flow will start. Since I am using PKCE, the flow needs to be completed in the browser since the PCKE details (code verifier) are stored in the cookies, which I cannot access from the app. The flow continues and the /signin endpoint is called within the in-app browser which will complete the flow.
Now the problem is how to get the session identifier handed over to the app. Currently I have implemented this with a final redirect (deep link) that carries the session identifier as query parameter. Due to limitation in the app framework (React Native) I do not have access to anything else (cookie, headers) than the URL and thereby query parameters.

It feels a bit unsafe to pass the session identifier (which can be used to access any protected endpoint in the system) to the app via query parameters. Therefore, my question is whether it is considered a better solution to disable PKCE and use deep linking for the authorization code exchange. That way, it will be possible to get the authorization code in the app, which then can call the `/signin` endpoint in the session manager to finalize the flow and obtain the session identifier in the response (either body or header).
As I understand, PKCE is mostly related to situations where the app acts as the client and therefore cannot store secrets in a secure manner. Since this is not the case here, I wonder if turning it off actually provides a better and more secure solution since the authorization code is one-time use only, compared to the session identifier that lives for at least 5 min.

You might wonder why the access token is not used as authorization mechanism, but that is simply because the identification/authentication is completely detached from the authorization engine (by design). This means, that the access token of the IDP can only be used to call endpoints within the IDP itself i.e. obtain certain details about the authenticated person.

Advices are more than welcome as well as alternative solutions to app based OIDC through in-app browsers.

**Update #1**

Just to highlight what I consider the core of the problem. I have a common setup for web and mobile which both uses the same session manager (backend for frontend OIDC client)

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = "url";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.ClientId = "ClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
}
```

When setting the scheme to cookie based, I am not able to pass the authorization code using the redirect URL to the app, since the .NET generated cookies cannot be acquired within the app.

It seems, by using a backend for frontend for mobile apps I am deviating from the standards where the app typically communicates directly with the IDP.

So I guess my question is - is it common to have two different approaches/setup across web and mobile?

Problem is though, that I need to have a session created in the session manager but that could potentially be done using the access token of the IDP.

Answer (score 1):

Usually mobile apps follow [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252), where the claimed HTTPS scheme based redirect URI is considered most secure, to prevent impersonation attacks. My [blog post and code example](https://authguidance.com/android-code-sample-overview/) show how this works.

PKCE should be used to protect against authorization code injection attacks when the app sends the code to the authorization server's token endpoint, since the mobile app is a public client.

A backend for frontend is used for web apps, to keep tokens out of the browser and thus reduce the impact of XSS exploits. It is not usually used for mobile apps. One reason is that a mobile session ID as an API credential might be usable by an attacker who steals one for a long time, whereas an access token typically has a lifetime of around 15 minutes.

Whatever solution you decide upon, the mobile app should receive the authorization code and send it to your backend, along with a PKCE code verifier. The backend can then return an API credential securely to the app.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that OIDC best practice actually dictate a different setup between web and mobile? In mobile you'll act as a direct client towards to IDP, but in web you'll introduce a backend for frontend acting as the client?

Comment: I do follow the logic in this - the problem is that the mentioned session manager is kind of important since it adds a certain amount of context to the login process. Also, the session manager is acutally our backend for frontend, originally build only for web purposes and afterwards extended to mobile. Therefore, we might be to trying to misuse the concept here.